# Update Athena Table from 2 external tables in Athena from s3

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena

I am relatively new to athena & s3.
I have an s3 bucket which contains 2 folders with csv files in both. I have created 2 external tables for each folder in athena.

I want to create another final table in athena which joins the two files and updates with more rows automatically as more files are added into the s3 bucket. Please could you advise the best way to get the output needed?

I have tried "create table from query" in athena. But the table remains static as i upload more files to s3, and doesnt update.

Answer (score 1):

For this use-case I would suggest creating a view in Athena. You can read more on it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/views.html).